# Xib not found on hardware test

Tags: iphone, ios, xib

(Beginner asks:) Seen similar posts before - everything fine on simulator, crashing on iPhone. This is the error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

I've read other posts here, but it's not the case-sensitivity issue, as far as I can tell.

One thing that might be a clue is that when I select the xib for editing, the assistant editor shows "No Assistant Results" instead of the header file. Can someone tell me what this means?

Answer (score 0):

In your App-info.plist there should be entries for the NIBs for both iPhone and iPad. Make sure these are specified correctly and the corresponding xib files are working.